# Delete all Rows from a workbook i just opened VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Problem: I need to delete all the cells except the header, i made a macro but doesn't work, says the length is wrong

Question: How to delete the entire rows.

I'll put the code i use to open the second workbook and my code.

```
Sub FileChooser()

Dim FileR As String

On Error Resume Next

FileR = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="File chooser test", _
                            filefilter:="Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")


If Not FileR = "False" Then
    MsgBox FileR
End If


Workbooks.Open FileName:=FileR
End Sub

Sub DeleteRows()
Workbooks("DetailT.xlsx").Activate
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("R_Online_2020").Range("2:1049576").Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook the code is in... which is not `FileR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, please:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("DetailT.xlsx")
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("R_Online_2020")
     sh.Range("A2:A" & sh.Range("A" & sh.Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

For applying the same deletion process to all workbook sheets, you can use the next code:

```
Sub DeleteRowsOfAllSheets()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
     Set wb = Workbooks("DetailT.xlsx")
     For Each sh in wb.Sheets
         sh.Range("A2:A" & sh.Range("A" & sh.Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru works perfectly! I have a question about Excel VBA, is it possible to work on several sheets at the same time, for example if the workbook has 10 other sheets with different names, can i add them to the set so i only have to write sh.Range 1 time so it deletes all from the other worksheets, hope i explained myself clearly.

Comment: @Zerrets: Yes, you can. You should iterate between `Workbok.Sheets`. Declare the workbook as above, the generic sheet as above and use `For each sh in wb.Sheets` ... repeat what the above code does in terms of sheet manipulation and end it with `Next`. In fact, I will add a piece of code to my answer. I am not sure you understand what I am writing here...

Comment: thank you very much, for the time you invested here, i have a lot to learn from excel vba because of work, i'm a newbie in macros but i understood everything you wrote.